# Xampp has image file save to a test db that wont display image

Tags: php, html, mysqli, xampp

I have inserted two images into test db on xampp, I wrote the several code for displaying the image. Yet run into error that I have screen shot:

I need to display an img in a div that upon click will display the file:

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$username = "daiori";
$password = "";
$db = "test";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $db);

$sql = "SELECT `pictures`, `filename` FROM `pictures`";
$run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
$pictures = array($rows=>id, $rows=>filename,$rows=>pictures);

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Type: image/gif");

function showFile(){
 $pictures;     
}

     $arrlength = count($pictures);
while($rows == true){
    for($i = 0; $i < $arrlength; $i++){
        base64_decode($pictures[$i], false);
    }
showFile(); 
}

?>
```

if you look at the screen shot the display error is shown. Can you explain the reason for the display error.
[image]

Comment: `echo base64_decode($pictures[$i], false);` ? try adding error_reporting(E_ALL) to find what error is thrown

Comment: Can you post your db table structure?

Comment: it's just basic...database is test...table is picture...three rows id, filename, pictures

Comment: I'll try E_ALL in a few

Comment: Ty Muhammad Omer Aslam, it's difficult to find at first, through frustrations, yet, the written code is

Comment: $arrlength = count($pictures);
while($rows == true){
 for($i = 0; $i < $arrlength; $i++){
  base64_decode($pictures[$i], false);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    }

Comment: which in xampp: apache (log) when initializing xampp shows error codes for ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_start_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);